# Suppose/assume that or supposing/assuming that

Tags: verb-forms, mathematics, participles

Which one is correct?

> Suppose/assume that X equals 1, we know X+1=2.

or

> Supposing/assuming that X equals 1, we know X+1=2.

It seems to me that using present participles makes more grammatical sense, but I've seen the first expression being used as well.

Comment: In math, I always view "Suppose" as an If/Then scenario. I intuitively make it, "... we *then* know..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In maths the forms *suppose* and *assume* are widely used.

The last part of the sentence is strange, though: I'd just use "*then* X+1=2".

*Then* is an implication, as *lurker* mentions in the comments, and the first condition must be triggered for the next step to work.

*Supposing* or *assuming* are often used when you have some work ahead of you, not when you want to establish a simple result. They are often used with an adverb like *finally*, *eventually*, etc.